# Is there something that would allow a Windows application source code to be recompiled to Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, operating-systems, wine

Think WINE but recompilation. Think Cygwin but the other way around.

If not, what are the challenges getting in the way?

Edit: I'm looking for something that works like WINE but can get me better performance, maybe through something like recompilation.

Comment: This is rather broad and could generate a number of opinion based answers...

Comment: There are frameworks that can compile to other OSses. This means that if your program is written using that framework, you can use the compiler that comes with that framework to create a build for another OS.

Comment: @Greenonline That isn't necessarily a bad thing. Options are good.

Comment: @AdityaPainuly For SuperUser and other stack exchange sites that IS a bad thing. SuperUser does not allow questions that seek opinions. See the help center on what kind of questions are considered on-topic and off-topic here.

Comment: @LPChip My question is not "primarily" opinion-based. I'm asking if anything like that exists at all. That is not an opinion based question like "What is the best OS?"

Comment: Editing source code to work on another platform is called `porting`. It's generally not considered trivial.

Comment: Further, what research have you done and what have you tried? We kinda expect people to have "done their homework", so to speak, researched and tried things. Also, being specific is good. Not "does this exist", but "I'm trying to do this specific action with this specific thing". So, your question should be "I'm trying to compile the code for this windows application to work on Linux, here's my research so far and here's what I've tried, and hers how it's failed."

Comment: @music2myear I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Your edit turns this question into another kind of off-topic questions: seeking software recommendations are also off-topic.

Comment: @LPChip Alright, where can I take this?

Comment: Probably to whoever wrote the original code.

Comment: It depends on what the code does. Consider using an existing open source alternative already in Linux

Comment: It depends on what type of binary the source code compiles to... What we are talking about? You have not disclosed what type of binary is produced - is it a full blown application, a service or what..? Your options, depending upon what it is that you wish to run, could include: *Emulation*; *VM*; full-blown *Porting*, or; you might be able to use a *Docker container*.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is going to be a no.

The way Operating systems work is fundamentally different between each type of OS. The way they handle with drivers and the way they deal with what is on the system differs enough that if you have the source code for one OS, you will have to transcode it yourself to something that may work on another OS using the tools from that other OS. It may even become apparent that some functions are just not possible on one OS as they interact with core features of that OS.

In order to get around this limitation, developers have created frameworks that you can use in your programming language. By using this language construct, you can compile the same source code to different operating systems (different binaries per OS) and it will always work. That really is the best option you have. Converting existing source code is going to be a real challenge. Not impossible, but requires a lot of skill and time, and there is no out-of-the-box solution available.

Comment: Important to point out that even if the uses a framework supported on multiple platforms, it has to be recompiled, and an individual applicable binary is generated. Universal binaries exist for Windows (x86-64 and ARM), (MacOS and iOS), Linux but compiling a single application to support all three isn’t possible

Comment: Added a bit of clarification to the answer.